# How to count words in a line

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a text file called "shoplist.txt" which one have:

```
drinks water cola fanta
fruit banana orange
```

And I want to get how many items per line I have. I'm able to extract drinks and fruit with function "cut" but how can I count how many words I have in each line?

My actually code is:

```
fileLine=`cat file.txt`
#Here I get each line saving it to fileLine
for line in $fileLine; do
 echo
((aux++))
done
```

But this code dosen't work because it save to %fileLine each work (drinks, then water,then cola,...)

How can I get the first line and then count the words on that line?

Comment: wc would do the necessary job in a loop.

Comment: Is the output of the `awk` script in the answer what you want to have? If not, what exactly do you want to get?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you can use `awk`, `NF` is the number of fields in the current line (by default, a field is a word delimited by any amount of whitespace).

Use

```
awk '{ print NF, $0 }' inputfile
```

With your sample input, this will print

```
4 drinks water cola fanta
3 fruit banana orange
```

Comment: The more cryptic `awk '$0=NF" "$0' inputfile` is a shorter solution.

Comment: @Isaac:  Really ? Is shorter better ? In this specific case Bodo's answer is just **the** answer to OP, ... and [s]he beat us all to it.  :-[

Comment: Thanks everyone for their advices. I didn't know about awk, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In Bash and `wc`:

```
IFS=$'\n'
while read line; do
    wc -w <<< "$line"
done < file.txt
```

`wc` counts lines, words, bytes in files. With a shell loop you can make it count words in a line.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware about WC -l for lines but not for words, thanks!

Comment: Upvote. Such a simple job no need to bother `awk`

Comment: Sure, @bruce. For 10,000 line file, why run awk when you can run 10,000 consecutive wc processes?

Comment: Yes, you are right @Paul_Pedant. If performance becomes an issue, we definitely will go a programming language, such as `awk`, `perl` or `python`, or `C` who knows. But before that, I'd like to keep it simple enough.

Comment: @bruce: But Bodo published a one-liner that does what the 4-line shell does, but probably 200 times faster, and it got 14 upvotes. It's hardly a "programming language" issue: it contains one simple command. How would you explain the simplicity of <<< in the Bash version, for example?

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe slightly out of context (though similar), as it concerns numbers aka (single) digits, but this supersimple awk-rule helped me out a lot to keep only those lines of a file with less than four times the high digits on each line:

```
awk -F [5,6,7,8,9] 'NF-1<4' IN > OUT
```

'NF-1' to obtain an exact count of 0, 1, 2 or 3 high digits (not more).

Comment: I have no idea what question you are answering. I see no evidence that you are answering *this* question.  If you believe that you have some knowledge, insight or wisdom that is not present anywhere else on this site, then [post a new question](/questions/ask) that asks the question that the above is an answer to, and then re-post this answer under it.